# How to delete text in all occurences of a specific tag in Latex

Tags: latex

In my latex document I have use the tag `\sout` , to strike out some texts, in many places. Is there a one-shot way to delete the text in all the occurrences of the tag along with the tag ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redefine the way `\sout` works by including the following in your document preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\sout}[1]{\unskip}
```

Here's an example illustrating the effect:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ulem
\begin{document}
Here is some \sout{text} stuff.

\renewcommand{\sout}[1]{\unskip}

Here is some \sout{text} stuff.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an editor that allows for searching with regular expressions, then you could do a find for the regular expression `\\sout\{[^\}]+\}` (note that this is untested) and replace with an empty string or space.